# How to separate hierarchical data and GUI?

Tags: c++

I heard that it is better to separate data and GUI. For examples, I have some data. It is  hierarchical with abstract base and derived class for concrete types, like

```
class Data {};
class ConcreteDataA : public Data {};
class ConcreteDataB : public Data {};
```

And I also have its hierarchical GUI (for example dialog)

```
class DataDialog {};
class ConcreteDataADialog : public DataDialog {};
class ConcreteDataBDilaog : public DataDialog {};
```

And I want create a data dialog object from a data object. If the data object is ConcreteDataA, ConcreteDataADialog is created, if B, B dialog is created. There is an easy way to do it by adding a virtual function in class Data like

```
virtual DataDialog* CreateDialog()
```

But if I add this function in the data class. it seems to violate the data/GUI separation principle. The second way is to build a global CreateDialog function, and create dialogs according to the dynamic_cast type of data object. This way is also not good for many maual ifs. Any other way to implement it? Or in practice, the first way is also okay? Thanks a lot!

One of my friends told me to use reflection. I think this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

An Abstract Factory is a design pattern in which different types of objects can be created depending on the argument. So in this example, the factory will create a `ConcreteDataADialog` or a `ConcreteDataBDilaog` depending on the type of the data.

Code sketch:

```
class DialogFactory {
public:
    virtual Dialog* createDialog() = 0;
};

class ADialogFactory : public DialogFactory {
public:
    Dialog* createDialog() {
        return new ADialog();
    }
};

class BDialogFactory : public DialogFactory {
public:
    Dialog* createDialog() {
        return new BDialog();
    }
};

class Application {

    Dialog* createSpecificDialog(Data data) {
        if (data.isA()) {
            return new ADialogFactory().createDialog();
        } else {
            return new BDialogFactory().createDialog();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show it with some simple code for my case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1899020 I added an example.

Comment: Instead of the manual ifs, you can add a virtual method to the Dialog class that gets a data object and returns a boolean, so that each Dialog will declare which data objects it supports.

Comment: Getting data from dilaog is okay. I want to get dialog from data. Thanks.

Comment: I know, that's what I meant. Given data A, you ask each dialog whether it supports data A, and if some dialog returns "true" then you use it.